# Azure Devops restoring from multiple private nuget sources (same type)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, pipeline

In Azure pipelines, the Nuget Restore task allows me to specify a feed in my organization. However, that feed can apparently only have one upstream source per type (nuget, npm, etc.), and that upstream source is nuget.org.
I have another nuget feed that I need to pull in as well, but since we're only allowed to have one upstream nuget source for our custom feeds, I'm not quite sure how best to tackle this.

edit: Actually, even after removing nuget.org as the upstream branch, I still can't add another upstream branch aside from NPM.. I thought it was unable to be selected because I already had Nuget.org included.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc： [Enable upstream sources in an existing feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#enable-upstream-sources-in-an-existing-feed)

> Custom public upstream sources are only supported with npm registries.

The cause of the issue is that custom public upstream sources are only supported with NPM registries. This is the limitation of Azure Artifacts.

For a workaround, to use multiple private nuget sources, you can define the nuget resource in Nuget.config file and create nuget Service connection in **Project Settings -> Service connections**.

Then you can use the service connections in nuget restore task.

For example:

[image]

**Update:**

Nuget Restore task sample:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: $(build.sourcesdirectory)/targetfolder/nuget.config
    externalFeedCredentials: 'nuget1027, test nuget feed'
```

Comment: welp... reading is fundamental. My bad.

The issue I ran into with the config file is that I have no clue what the path is. I added Nuget.config to the same folder as the sln to no avail, and I got: 
"Not found nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config" (have tried changing the case a few ways)

Comment: The issue points that the nuget.config file not able to be found. You can try to define the nuget.config path: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/targetfolder/nuget.config`

Comment: I think this will work, but I've just realized that I can't run this on a linux VM right now to fully vet that the restore completes successfully as ubuntu-latest is only packaged up to .NET 6 support right now. I'll update you whenever that's been resolved.

Comment: Feel free to share the result. If the answer can help you solve the issue, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: I think it will, but I didn't want to prematurely accept it if this same nuget restore task still fails for some other reason once I get past this current error (error : Version 7.0.101 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.10.1.31701. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available). 
I'm presently using the UseDotnet@2 task to install .NET 7 SDK manually, but the wrong MSBuild version is still being used now. So I'm unable to verify.

Comment: To use version 17.3.0 of MSBuild or higher, you can try to use windows-2022 microsoft-hosted agent. The msbuild tool(17.4.0)  has been pre-installed on the agent

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the windows version in my pipeline as there are some script steps (that really should be using PS core +), but I was able to move this up as the first step and confirm that this part works. I was trying to find the right settings to get it to work in ubuntu after a manual SDK upgrade to no avail. But this working in windows is enough to confirm a valid answer for my question. thanks!